# Por qué mi Localhost no muestra mi Html

Tags: php

Hace poco me pase para un entorno Linux más específicamente "Kali" instale el Xampp y Sublime Text, pero al momento de ejecutar mi aplicación no me muestra nada y es porque el  código PHP esta escrito primero que el HTML. Pero esto no pasaba en Windows. Alguien sabe que sucede?

Estructura de mi codigo:

Codigo que no me muestra nada:

PHP:

```
<php 

  include 'config.php';

  session_start();

  error_reporting(0);

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $password = md5($_POST['password']);

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND password='$password'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
       header("Location: inicio.php");
     } else {
       echo "<script>alert('Credenciales incorrectas...')</script>";
}
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <form>
     <p class="login-text" style="font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 800;">Iniciar seión</p>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" required>
    </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button name="submit" class="btn">Iniciar Sesión</button>
        </div>
      <p class="login-register-text">No tienes una cuenta? <a href="registro.php">Registrate acá</a></p>
   </form>
</body>
```

Codigo que si me muestra algo pero el PHP ya no funciona:

HTML:

```
<body>
   <form>
     <p class="login-text" style="font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 800;">Iniciar seión</p>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" required>
    </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <button name="submit" class="btn">Iniciar Sesión</button>
        </div>
      <p class="login-register-text">No tienes una cuenta? <a href="registro.php">Registrate acá</a></p>
   </form>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<php 

  include 'config.php';

  session_start();

  error_reporting(0);

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $password = md5($_POST['password']);

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND password='$password'";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
       header("Location: inicio.php");
     } else {
       echo "<script>alert('Credenciales incorrectas...')</script>";
}
}
?>
```

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿En qué ruta estas guardando el archivo? ¿El archivo tiene extensión `.php`? ¿Probaste un *"hola mundo"* en el root de localhost? `<?php echo "hola mundo";`

Comment: El orden no debería importar, con tal de que las etiquetas estén bien puestas, cada cosa esté en su sitio (por lo general el bloque PHP o o que se produce en él iría dentro de la etiqueta `body`  del HTML), el archivo tenga la extensión correcta y tu entorno esté bien instalado. ¿Por qué dices que es problema del orden? ¿Si lo pones al revés funciona? Si es así, muéstranos ambos códigos, el que funciona y el que no.

Comment: Apache tiene un módulo `dir` y en la configuración puedes modificar el orden en que deben cargarse los archivos `index.*`, si aparece primero `index.html` ese es el que se va a cargar. Por lo general el archivo está en `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` y necesitas abrirlo con permisos de administrador para poder modificarlo.

Comment: La mejor forma de explicar cómo está armado todo es incluyendo un ejemplo mínimo de cómo está armado el PHP y cómo intentas cargarlo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: @Triby Encontre el archivo pero según entiendo esta cargando el html primero:  DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm, o tiene que estar primero index.php?

Comment: @aeportugal Claro fue lo primero que hice, la carpeta se esta guardando en el htdocs, solo tengo archivos ".php"

Comment: @A.Cedano Mira acabe de anexar el codigo.

Comment: Por favor, pon ambos códigos como texto, no como imagen. El texto es más fácil de analizar que la imagen y es más fácil para ti, porque sólo es copiar y pegar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo, ahi esta en texto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Mira en el orden que te las puse es como lo tengo en mi codigo, es decir, el primero archivo es Primero PHP y luego HTML y el segundo es primero HTML y luego PHP

Comment: Hagamos una cosa, en tu primer bloque de código, cambia temporalmente esto: `error_reporting(0);` por estas tres líneas de código: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Luego guarda el archivo e intenta ejecutarlo. Dinos si ves algo en pantalla. Puede que simplemente haya error en tu código y no se muestre nada.

Comment: @A.Cedano Acabe de poner las 3 lineas de codigo, y me sigue aparenciendo en blanco completamente.

Comment: Intenta crear un nuevo archivo con extensión `.php` que tenga este contenido: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mi pagina de prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    echo "Hola mundo";
  ?>
  </body>
</html>` Si observas, faltan partes en tu HTML y puede que ese sea el problema. Si ese archivo básico, bien estructurado, tampoco se muestra, entonces puede que haya un problema en tu entorno, con la instalación o el intérprete de PHP.

Comment: @A.Cedano Con eso si me dio y me mostro, correctamente el "Hola Mundo"

Comment: OK, entonces, en base a esa misma estructura, monta tu código PHP que no funciona, poniéndolo en lugar del `Hola Mundo`, dentro de la parte `body` del HTML. Deja las tres líneas de reporte de error que te sugerí antes, para que si hay algún error te lo muestre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. La etiqueta de apertura de bloques PHP es esta: `<?php`
2. Si estás integrando el contenido que generará tu código PHP, debes colocarlo en la parte de ese HTML donde irán los datos, que suele ser la etiqueta `body` del HTML.

Corrigiendo esas dos cosas, el código debería funcionar (dejaré el reporte de errores encendido **temporalmente** para que te muestre los errores si los hubiera, luego lo puedes apagar):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AQUÍELTITULODETUPAGINA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    include 'config.php';

    session_start();

    /*Desactivar estas tres líneas cuando funcione*/
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');     
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');     
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    # error_reporting(0);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $user = $_POST['user'];
       $password = md5($_POST['password']);

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND password='$password'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
         $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
         header("Location: inicio.php");
       } else {
         echo "<script>alert('Credenciales incorrectas...')</script>";
    }
    }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te agradezco por la ayuda!!